# Update the companyName attribute for an Azure AD user via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, entra-id, office365

**Background**

I have an email system (CodeTwo) that creates signatures automatically using AD attributes for users.  Many of my users are synchronised between an on-prem AD and Office 365 / AAD, however newer users are cloud only, that is, they are created in the Office 365 admin portal and are not synchronised with an on-prem user.

**The problem**

I am using the `companyName` attribute, which is easily set through the properties dialog of the Windows Admin Tool **Active Directory Users & Computers**.  I have setup **Azure AD Connect** to include this attribute in synchronisation.  For my synced users, this setup works as expected - using commands like `Get-CsOnleUser` and `Get-AzureADUser` I can see the `Company` or `CompanyName` properties are set correctly. For cloud-only users, however, this value is always blank.

I cannot find a way of setting this value - the property is either read-only, or changing the value of the attribute and using `Set-CsUser` or `Set-AzureADUser` has no effect.

I noticed that we had some AD Extension properties, in particular one called `extension_0000000000000000000000000000000_company` - I can set this for the cloud users, but it doesn't seem to affect the object returned from the queries above.  Similarly it is not picked up by the signature stamping system.

**The question**

How does one set the `companyName` attribute for users in Azure AD / Office 365? Preferably using PowerShell, but open to any options at this stage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the problem and had to ask Microsoft directly. Since February 2019, CompanyName is writable.

Command is

```
Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId <UPN> -ExtensionName "CompanyName" -ExtensionValue "<VALUE>"
```

Check my blogpost on the matter for the whole explanation: http://www.yasab.net/azure-ad-update-companyname/

Answer (score 1):

> How does one set the companyName attribute for users in Azure AD /
>   Office 365?

For now, customer can use Azure AD connect to sync on-prem AD user's attribute `company` to Azure AD, but **can't** set `company` for cloud user, the attribute `company` is **read only**.

Here a similar [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c920cef6-3dbc-4b96-b3c1-ef59a1c75620/cannot-update-companyname-attribute?forum=WindowsAzureAD) about you:

> This attribute `company` is inherited from the Display name property of the
>   organisation but is not visible in the Graph API directly.

As a workaround, you can create users to your on-prem AD, then sync to Azure AD.

About attribute `extension_0000000000000000000000000000000_company`, used for mapping attribute.

Comment: Thanks Jason - I have read that post but, in my case at least, the DisplayName property of the organisation is set but is not flowing through to the companyName attribute.  Further, we're not talking about the GraphAPI at all in this case.  Adding the user to an on-prem AD and then syncing is not an option in this case (we are trying to get rid of the on-Prem AD, not use it more).

Comment: @RichardHauer Azure AD powershell use the GraphAPI, so we can't use PowerShell to set it.

Comment: I see. That’s disappointing.

Comment: Jason how about employeeid and pager field? are they read only or can they be synced to azure ad via Ad connect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the value set by using the set-user cmdlet

```
set-user JDoe -Company "Fabrikam Inc."
```

It also populates Get-AzureADUser CompanyName attribute.